# Azure application insights, nested object in Custom Dimension appears as [object Object ]

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, opencensus

I have a nested object which i send through the custom dimension to azure appInsights logs
below is the object

```
{
   .
   .
  'special_chars':'6'
  'storage_acc_name':'subrodecadlsdev',
  'top_10_line_width':{
       'LW_101':45,
       'LW_229':78,
       'LW_77':67
    }
}
```

The **top_10_lines_width** object is coming as **[object Object]** in customdimension. Below is the pic

[image]

I tried using this query but no luck

```
extend tp = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions['top_10_line_width']))
```

This is how the result looks
[image]

Does this have to do with the object? As it cant be extracted as rows. If so then how do I extract it, I just need the message and tp column to show as a dashboard

So for the context, I am using python, and using opencenus SDK for logging here is the code snippet specifying how I send the logs and custom properties using customdimensions

```
import logging

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# TODO: replace the all-zero GUID with your instrumentation key.
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
)

counts_dict = {
  'special_chars':'6'
  'storage_acc_name':'subrodecadlsdev',
  'top_10_line_width':{
       'LW_101':45,
       'LW_229':78,
       'LW_77':67
    }
}

#this is the line where I am adding my custom props to customdimensions
properties = {'custom_dimensions': counts_dict}  

# Use properties in logging statements
logger.warning('action', extra=properties)
```

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#introducing-opencensus-python-sdk) to official ms docs

Comment: Can you please attach a fiddler session of how you actually send it? Which SDK do you use?

Comment: @ZakiMa I am using opencensus which is a python SDK. I have added the code snippet and link to the official docs to the question

Comment: This helps. Would it be also possible to see a fiddler stream? I'm interested in how exactly this object got serialized. The value is supposed to be a string, not an object. If it is serialized as such then the problem is in backend, otherwise it is in SDK (or you might need to serialize it manually to string).

Comment: You were right. Serialization was the issue, I serialized the top_10_line_width and then the issue is resolved. So I did like this `counts_dict['top_10_line_width'] = json.dumps(top_10_line_width)`